# add activity dashlet for accounts module in sugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

**I need to add activity stream dashlet for the accounts module and also the opportunities related to this account**

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get solution by referring below links:

[Creating new dashlets based on default](http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2013/04/25/creating-new-dashlets-based-on-default/)

[Creating dashlets](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/02_Application_Framework/Dashlets/01_Creating_Dashlets/)